# JSDoc is this how you mark a @typedef as @global?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc, jsdoc3

Just making sure that this in a module in our Node server is the right way to be able to use an `@typedef` throughout the application instead of repeating it in every module/file it is needed.  From the docs I can't determine if this is correct or not, and does anyone have an opinion on where to store global @typedefs so they are easy to find if they need to be changed when used throughout the application.

```
/**
 * Universally unique identifier.
 * @global
 * @typedef {string} UUID
 */
```

Comment: Did you ever determine if this was correct?

Comment: No, but I ended up using it anyway since the code needed documentation, and this was how the docs appeared to steer its usage.  Even now no one has changed it so my team doesn't have any better idea of the proper use, but it feels like it provides clarity, and is easy to determine the intent, which might be enough.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Guess I'll use it too! Hopefully we can get an "official" answer to this someday - I just scoured the `@global` and `@typedef` docs again + Google to no avail :(

Answer (score 8):

A bit of a late answer here, but I came across this issue from Google, so this is how I solved this issue for myself. Hopefully it helps future people!

I ran into a similar situation where I had a `typedef` in a module and wanted to use that type elsewhere in the application, without redefining the type.

I went with something like this:

```
myModule.js
/**
 * Universally unique identifier.
 * @typedef {string} UUID
 */
```

```
myOtherScript.js

/**
 * @function
 * @param {import('path/to/myModule.js').UUID} uuid
 */
function getByUUID(uuid) { ... }
```

This doesn't make the `typedef` strictly global, so you cannot do `@param {UUID} uuid` (which *would* be cleaner, however I've yet to find a way to achieve this) but this approach worked for my use-case, and **definitely** is better than rewriting the type everywhere it is used.

More info around this topic can be found in [this Github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25386).