# JSDoc: How to specify the type of an implicit global variable for a JS code snippet?

Tags: typescript, jsdoc

I have a JavaScript file that is being run with `eval()` by a VSCode extension. When the script is evaluated, its context already includes the global variable `vscode` (the VSCode API) which I am using from my script. All of that works fine.

What I want to know: Is there a way to use JSDoc annotations / TypeScript type definition files to tell VSCode that the `vscode` variable exists in the context?

I have tried this (I'm not sure if it makes any sense) and it didn't help:

```js
// @ts-check
/// <reference path="node_modules/@types/vscode/index.d.ts" />
```

What does work is if I write:

```
const vscode = require('vscode')
```

But I'd rather not have to include that line because `vscode` already exists in the context.

---

**UPDATE: More failed attempts**

I tried creating a file `types.d.ts`:

```js
export {}

declare global {

  var vscode: any
}
```

Referenced from the JS:

```js
/// <reference path="types.d.ts" />
```

This works to satisfy the type checker of the existence of the global object, but I don't want `vscode` to be of type `any`. I want it to be the actual type of the `vscode` object. I don't know what that type is though. I can't find a type definition for it, only a module definition:

```
declare module 'vscode' {
     ...
}
```

Is that the type? How can I use it?

I've tried:

```js
export {}
import vscode from 'vscode'

declare global {

  var vscode: vscode
}
```

But that fails on the import: "Module 'vscode' has no default export."
or, if I put braces around the name, "Module 'vscode' has no exported member 'vscode'"

Any suggestions?

---

**UPDATE: Success!**

I've worked out how to do it. I needed to use `typeof` to get the type of the module.

```js
export {}

declare global {

  var vscode: typeof import('vscode')
}
```

There's probably a way to do it more directly with JSDoc annotations in the JavaScript, but I want the `types.d.ts` file for other types anyway.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JSDoc is this how you mark a @typedef as @global?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46436950/jsdoc-is-this-how-you-mark-a-typedef-as-global)

Comment: I suspect it's something along those lines, but I don't know exactly what to write. 'vscode' is declared as a module and I don't know how to use a module as a type. I think I'm missing some important concepts.

Comment: Hmm, I looked at vscode extension docs (https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension#debugging-the-extension) and it seems that they import it as a module. Can this be applied to your case?

Comment: No, because I want to avoid using imports in my JS. But thanks for your suggestion because it helped me realise what I need to do.